# how to setup your own ipfs node to remix settings?

Tags: remix, ipfs

i keep getting the following error while publishing in ipfs from remix IDE

Failed to publish metadata file and sources to ipfs, please check the ipfs gateways is available.
Error: HTTPError: project id required
,TypeError: Failed to fetch

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Project in https://app.infura.io/dashboard to get Project ID and Secret Key
2. After login to above link, click "Create new API Key" and select Network as IPFS and choose a project name.

You will get a project ID and secret key. Fill those details in Remix, under settings.
[image]

Comment: Infura's IPFS node requires credit card info and its free account has only 5GB storage limit. As I just deployed my own local IPFS node I want to connect my local node rather than Infura's to Remix IDE. Is it possible?